# Mock both abstract class and its subclass

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I need to mock out class of depending library.

Actual implementation class is correctly mocked

```
@Mock
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBeanMock;
```

but there is call to its abstract class and I cannot mock that method.

I'm using Mockito currently.

I have tried to mock it this way

```
@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
```

it passes actuall call somehow,
but then it fails on verification.

Here is complete class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DatabaseConfigTest {

DatabaseConfig databaseConfig;

@Mock
DriverManagerDataSource dataSourceMock;

@Mock
JpaTransactionManager transactionManagerMock;

@Mock
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactoryMock;

@Mock
HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapterMock;

@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBeanMock;

@Test
public void testEntityManagerFactory() throws Exception {
    doReturn(vendorAdapterMock).when(databaseConfig).getHibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    doReturn(entityManagerFactoryBeanMock).when(databaseConfig).getLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    doReturn(dataSourceMock).when(databaseConfig).dataSource();

    EntityManagerFactory managerFactory = databaseConfig.entityManagerFactory();

    assertNotNull(managerFactory);
    verify(vendorAdapterMock, times(1)).setGenerateDdl(Boolean.TRUE);
    verify(entityManagerFactoryBeanMock, times(1)).setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapterMock);
    verify(entityManagerFactoryBeanMock, times(1)).setDataSource(dataSourceMock);
    verify(entityManagerFactoryBeanMock, times(1)).afterPropertiesSet(); // method from abstract - this method i cannot mock
}
}
```

Here is code from implementation:

```
factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter); // mocked, it doesn't enter
factory.setDataSource(dataSource()); // mocked, it doesn't enter          
factory.afterPropertiesSet(); // method from abstract, it enters here but shouldn't
```

Comment: please, show your code

Comment: Can you show the call to the method in the abstract class that's causing the problem?

Comment: How is `afterPropertiesSet` declared in the superclass?  Is it `final`?

Comment: It is final method.

Comment: so remove the final key word from the method and add a JavaDoc comment that this method should not be overwritten.

Comment: That class is from Spring library.

Comment: The short answer is that Mockito can't be used to change the behaviour of a `final` method.  Are you sure you need to do this?

Comment: I just have to ensure that the method is called. Are there any other way?